# How to develop an event receiver on selecting item from dropdownlist

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column

In my SharePoint list,I have a lookup column.
When I select one item from the lookup,I need to show the information from the selected one(like title,ID...).
I think that developing an event receiver on selecting item could resolve the problem.
or there is another way ?

Any ideas.

Comment: Can you please add more details about what you are trying to do?

Comment: I founs a solution , using jquery.this is the aricle that i followed : http://sharepointsps.blogspot.com/2012/11/spdisplayrelatedinfo-in-sp-2010-jquery.html